# Finding kth element in the nth order of Farey Sequence

Tags: algorithm, sequence, computer-science

Farey sequence of order n is the sequence of completely reduced fractions, between 0 and 1 which when in lowest terms have denominators less than or equal to n, arranged in order of increasing size. Detailed explanation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence).

[image]

**Problem**

The problem is, given n and k, where n = order of seq and k = element index, can we find the particular element from the sequence. For examples answer for (n=5, k =6) is 1/2.

**Lead**

There are many less than optimal solution available, but am looking for a near-optimal one. One such algorithm is discussed [here](https://csacademy.com/contest/algorithms-2018-07-22-6/task/farey_sequence/solution/), for which I am unable to understand the logic hence unable to apply the examples.

**Question**

Can some please explain the solution with more detail, preferably with an example.

Thank you.

Comment: Consider this paper: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.208.718&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read the method provided in your link, and the accepted C++ solution to it. Let me post them, for reference:

**Editorial Explanation**

> Several less-than-optimal solutions exist. Using a priority queue, one
>   can iterate through the fractions (generating them one by one) in O(K
>   log N) time. Using a fancier math relation, this can be reduced to
>   O(K). However, neither of these solution obtains many points, because
>   the number of fractions (and thus K) is quadratic in N.
>
> The “good” solution is based on meta-binary search. To construct this
>   solution, we need the following subroutine: given a fraction A/B
>   (which is not necessarily irreducible), find how many fractions from
>   the Farey sequence are less than this fraction. Suppose we had this
>   subroutine; then the algorithm works as follows:
>
> - Determine a number X such that the answer is between X/N and (X+1)/N; such a number can be determined by binary searching the range
>     1...N, thus calling the subroutine O(log N) times.
>
>   - Make a list of all fractions A/B in the range X/N...(X+1)/N. For any given B, there is at most one A in this range, and it can be
>       determined trivially in O(1).
>   - Determine the appropriate order statistic in this list (doing this in O(N log N) by sorting is good enough).
>
> It remains to show how we can construct the desired subroutine. We
>   will show how it can be implemented in O(N log N), thus giving a O(N
>   log^2 N) algorithm overall. Let us denote by C[j] the number of
>   irreducible fractions i/j which are less than X/N. The algorithm is
>   based on the following observation: C[j] = floor(X*B/N) – Sum(C[D],
>   where D divides j). A direct implementation, which tests whether any D
>   is a divisor, yields a quadratic algorithm. A better approach,
>   inspired by Eratosthene’s sieve, is the following: at step j, we know
>   C[j], and we subtract it from all multiples of j. The running time of
>   the subroutine becomes O(N log N).

**Relevant Code**

```
#include <cassert>

#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

const int kMaxN = 2e5;
typedef int int32;
typedef long long int64_x;
// #define int __int128_t
// #define int64 __int128_t

typedef long long int64;


int64 count_less(int a, int n) {
    vector<int> counter(n + 1, 0);
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i += 1) {
        counter[i] = min(1LL * (i - 1), 1LL * i * a / n);
    }

    int64 result = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i += 1) {
        for (int j = 2 * i; j <= n; j += i) {
            counter[j] -= counter[i];
        }
        result += counter[i];
    }

    return result;
}

int32 main() {
//    ifstream cin("farey.in");
//    ofstream cout("farey.out");
    int64_x n, k; cin >> n >> k;
    assert(1 <= n);
    assert(n <= kMaxN);
    assert(1 <= k);
    assert(k <= count_less(n, n));

    int up = 0;
    for (int p = 29; p >= 0; p -= 1) {
        if ((1 << p) + up > n) 
            continue;

        if (count_less((1 << p) + up, n) < k) {
            up += (1 << p);
        }
    }

    k -= count_less(up, n);

    vector<pair<int, int>> elements;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i += 1) {
        int b = i;
        // find a such that up/n < a / b and a / b <= (up+1) / n
        int a = 1LL * (up + 1) * b / n;
        if (1LL * up * b < 1LL * a * n) {
        } else {
            continue;
        }

        if (1LL * a * n <= 1LL * (up + 1) * b) {
        } else {
            continue;
        }

        if (__gcd(a, b) != 1) {
            continue;
        }

        elements.push_back({a, b});
    }

    sort(elements.begin(), elements.end(), 
            [](const pair<int, int>& lhs, const pair<int, int>& rhs) -> bool {
                return 1LL * lhs.first * rhs.second < 1LL * rhs.first * lhs.second; 
            });

    cout << (int64_x)elements[k - 1].first << ' ' << (int64_x)elements[k - 1].second << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

**Basic Methodology**

The above editorial explanation results in the following simplified version. Let me start with an example.

Let's say, we want to find 7th element of Farey Sequence with N = 5.

1. We start with writing a subroutine, as said in the explanation, that gives us the "k" value (how many Farey Sequence reduced fractions there exist before a given fraction - the given number may or may not be reduced)

So, take your F5 sequence:

```
k = 0,  0/1
k = 1,  1/5
k = 2,  1/4
k = 3,  1/3
k = 4,  2/5
k = 5,  1/2
k = 6,  3/5
k = 7,  2/3
k = 8,  3/4
k = 9,  4/5
k = 10, 1/1
```

If we can find a function that finds the count of the previous reduced fractions in Farey Sequence, we can do the following:

```
int64 k_count_2 = count_less(2, 5); // result = 4
int64 k_count_3 = count_less(3, 5); // result = 6
int64 k_count_4 = count_less(4, 5); // result = 9
```

This function is written in the accepted solution. It uses the exact methodology explained in the last paragraph of the editorial.

As you can see, the `count_less()` function generates the same `k` values as in our hand written list.

We know the values of the reduced fractions for k = 4, 6, 9 using that function. What about k = 7? As explained in the editorial, we will list all the reduced fractions in range **X/N and (X+1)/N**, here X = 3 and N = 5.

Using the function in the accepted solution (its near bottom), we list and sort the reduced fractions.

After that we will rearrange our k values, as in to fit in our new array as such:

```
k = -,  0/1
k = -,  1/5
k = -,  1/4
k = -,  1/3
k = -,  2/5
k = -,  1/2
k = -,  3/5 <-|
k = 0,  2/3   | We list and sort the possible reduced fractions 
k = 1,  3/4   | in between these numbers
k = -,  4/5 <-|
k = -, 1/1
```

(That's why there is this piece of code: `k -= count_less(up, n);`, it basically remaps the k values)

(And we also subtract one more during indexing, i.e.: `cout << (int64_x)elements[k - 1].first << ' ' << (int64_x)elements[k - 1].second << '\n';`. This is just to basically call the right position in the generated array.)

So, for our new re-mapped k values, for N = 5 and k = 7 (original k), our result is 2/3.

(We select the value k = 0, in our new map)

If you compile and run the accepted solution, it will give you this:

```
Input:  5 7 (Enter)
Output: 2 3
```

I believe this is the basic point of the editorial and accepted solution.